# How to pass values between asp.net pages with gridviews

Tags: asp.net, gridview, post

I enabled the selection on my gridview. The question is, I can pass values with buttons but it seems redundant, because I have selection linkbuttons. So how can I pass variables with them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/04/linkbutton-gridview-querystring.html) shows how to work with LinkButton in GridView and pass / transfer variable or data to other page and populate another gridview based on it **using QueryString and QueryStringParameters.** What's more, there is no need of any code behind. Pretty cool.